# Log.d and impact on performance

Tags: android, logging, debugging

I'm not entirely sure about what I'm reading in the documentation. Is it ok to leave a bunch of log.d pieces of code scattered about, or should I comment them out so that they don't impact my app's performance.

Thanks,

I'm a little confused because if you read about the log object ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)) you see this:

> "The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN,
>   INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an
>   application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but
>   stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept. "

It almost sounded like it's ok to leave debug messages in there because they are "stripped." Anyway, thanks for the answers, I'll comment them out when I'm done. Not like I need them in there once the app is completed.

Thanks

Comment: Besides impacting your app's performance, they potentially make it harder for other people to debug their stuff.  The log is only 64KB, so every time you add a log message some other message gets pushed off the top.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Log has impact on performance, so it's recommended that you comment it out or log with conditional statements.

For example

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
// Debugging
 private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
 private static final boolean D = true;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "MyActivity.onCreate debug message");
 }
```

Then in when you publish your release version just change "D" to false

Comment: Why don't you set debuggable=false to disable debug in app: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false">

Comment: @anticafe Because if for example you do a concatenation in a Log statement, it will still run (causing unnecessary allocations). Settings `debuggable = false` only ensures that it won't end up in the log. The methods will still get called.

Comment: Even better, use Proguard to strip out all the logs from the code.

Comment: I think the best solution is to use a third party loggin library such as Timber http://timber.io     so you can customize your app log behabior depending if it is in production or debug mode.

Answer (score 11):

My solution:

- Add unguarded log statements wherever you like
- [Strip them out for release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/deactivate-any-calls-to-log-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662)

Comment: by far the best solution IMHO - does not pollute code at all :)

Comment: but then you cannot turn them on again

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely comment them out.  They add up quickly and could noticeably slow down your app, especially if you have them in loops.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use code guard methods.

```
if (Log.isLoggable(LOG_TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Your log here");
}
```

Comment: Even this check has performance implications. I just ran Traceview and Log.isLoggable() takes 5ms CPU Time/Call and almost 11ms Real Time/Call.

Comment: You're right. But much better than writing a log info to disk. And the level is configurable through server's configs.

Comment: It is definitely better than writing to disk, but not good if you're trying to render frames at 60fps consistently. It's taking a good chunk out of that 16.7ms per frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yes print, println, Log.d, Log.e and all similar methods affect performance.

**The solution**

create a class named *C*

```
class C{
public static String TAG="My_debug_tag";
public static boolean isInTesting=true;

public static void log(String tag, String msg){
 if(!isInTesting) return;

Log.d(tag==null?TAG:tag, msg);
 
}
}
```

and use these methods for all your logs, and when you are ready to generate final .apk/.aab just set **isInTesting=false** to disable all logs from this method.