# Android: disable log output from 3rd party libraries

Tags: android, logcat

How can I disable the logcat output of 3rd party libraries, such as AdWhirl and AdMob?

Sometimes they provide a method to disable the log output, sometimes they don't. For those who don't is there a application wide setting where I can suppress either any log output or log output from certain classes or tags?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using ProGuard to remove the Log.* calls from the bytecode of the libraries.

See this answer: [Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/deactivate-any-calls-to-log-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662)

Comment: I'm using a third party .aar.  It looks like ProGuard has no effect.  Are you sure this works with .jars?