# Is there a shortcut to remove all Log statements from an Android project made in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to remove all the `Log` statements that I had added when I was making my android project. This is because I am now shipping the final project to my client.

Is there a shortcut which will automatically find all the `Log` statements and delete them?

This would spare the labor of going to individual `Log` statements and then deleting them.

Comment: In short, no.  In fact, you've probably wasted more time looking for a "non-labor-intensive" solution than you would have if you'd just done a "find references" search.

Comment: In addition, as someone here on SOF said (sorry, can't find it now), `verbose` and `debug` logs are not compiled in release mode, so you can let them be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Eclipse, type `android.util.Log`, place your cursor on the word `Log`, and press ctrl+shift+g or cmd+shift+g to find all references to it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use ProGuard to strip them automatically. See [Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/deactivate-any-calls-to-log-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this)

Answer (score 0):

**build.gradle**

buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

**proguard-rules.pro**

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }