# Removing Logs before uploading to GooglePlay

Tags: android, performance

I have read quite a few questions regarding "Removing Logs" but none answered my question. So, I have to ask here again.

What is the impact of `Log.d()` or `Log.v()` or `Syso()` statements, on the application?

Let's say I have an application with 200 `syso()` statements, or Logs, that I used to debug while creating the app. I didn't bother to remove them, because, (I am a newbie in android) and I thought, there is no way those statements gets printed or displayed. So, why take the pain of removing all those lines.

So how far my idea of not removing the logs effect the application? Will it increase the size of the application (cached data or something)?

@All, I think you don't are misunderstanding what I am asking for. I know Google advises us to remove the logs, and I am not questioning that. I want to know, what's the impact of those logs on my application, if i don't remove the logs

Comment: before adding a log just add DEBUG flag.

Comment: Yeah i understand that. I want to know what happens if i don't?

Comment: the user can see those logs.

Comment: oh.. How? Where can they see those logs?

Comment: 1. the same way you see them.
2. he can download any application to watch the logs.

Comment: If you can answer it separately, I can accept your answer.

Comment: All that logging uses processing resource hence battery.  For my app if I profile with the logging all still on it takes up a good chunk of the profile.  Any number printing stuff is usually very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove all log messages. Else the user can see them via logcat. But nothing will happen with your app (no increase size etc.)

Read this if you want to know how to remove them on the fly while deploying:
[Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this)

Comment: Do we have a logcat on Mobile? Can users see the logs after the application has been installed from GooglePlay on to the mobile, through Logcat?

Comment: If the users can see logcat from Mobile, where do I find the logcat on my Mobile?

Comment: Yep this is possible. Either via LogCat with his PC or several Apps which give the possibility to read them on the device itself.

Comment: e.g. with this app you can see LogCat messages on your device: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

Answer (score 0):

Read the section - **Preparing Your Application for Release**
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html