# Is using an if (debug) statement recommended?

Tags: android, performance

I am planning to add a DEBUG flag, and adding an `if statement` before every `Log.d` call

```
 public static final boolean DEBUG = FALSE;
 if (DEBUG)
 {
    Log.d(TAG,"Debug"); //dead code
 }
```

Will the dead code going to be removed in compile time, or will the `if statement` is going to be called on every time ?

Comment: You might consider using an advanced logging library; or using ProGuard to remove the `Log` calls from your bytecode. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this

Comment: @user46874: the proguard seems to be useful, I will give it a try, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debug code will always be executed (always the if).
By the way, Android already has this type of flag: `BuildConfig.DEBUG`

Comment: What about the performance issues? are they noticeable if I have around 300-400 log calls? Or should I just comment out/delete the logs?

Comment: If you use the BuildConfig.DEBUg flag I may even think it will be optimized by the compiler. This is because the piece of code in the If statement will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it increase the verbosity of the code, simply use a log library for this purpose, like [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) for example ...

```
logger.debug("Here is some DEBUG");
```

In Android you can use [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) ...

Comment: I'm talking about android, I will remove the Java tag, just for the case of confusion.

Comment: In Android you can use android-logging-log4j, take a look at the updated answer ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not removed completely but there is next no performance impact due to branch prediction of the CPU.

Ideally you should use the logging level of the logger to determine whether the logger should be called.

Note: a simple method call like this has next to no overhead whether you check or not (and the library should check)  Where you get a performance advantage is if you are doing something in the log message like

```
LOGGER.debug("The map is " + map);
```

In this case, the debug message will only be displayed if the debug is enable, however the string message will be build every time meaning this is more efficient.

```
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
    LOGGER.debug("The map is " + map);
```