# Cannot stripe out the Log outputs of the linked library using ProGuard

Tags: android, logging, apk, proguard

I am using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this) to get rid of the Logs in my release APK. I use the following config for that:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontobfuscate
-forceprocessing
-optimizationpasses 5
-keepattributes
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

This works when it comes to my own Log calls. However, I link to a library in my project, which is also in my Workspace. As far as I know this config should apply for the linked library too. But the `Log.d(...)` outputs from the linked library are still there when I run the release APK on my USB connected device. I cannot get them stripped out. Why not?

BTW, I use the *right click -> android tools -> Export signed APK* method in Eclipse ADT bundle for generating the release APK.

Comment: Are you sure `Log.d` is used within the library? Could be `Log.println`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that only Log.d is used. I can see the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove logging, you need to make sure that ProGuard's optimization step is enabled. It is disabled in the default configuration file in the Android SDK. Replace `proguard-android.txt` by `proguard-android-optimize.txt` in your `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Note that ProGuard doesn't make any distinction between your code and library code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I find this strange because using just `proguard-android.txt` _DID_ remove the logs from _my own project_. But the log outputs from the linked project were still printing. This contradicts with the comment "ProGuard doesn't make any distinction between your code and library code". But anyway, I changed the `proguard-android.txt` to `proguard-android-optimize.txt` and now I'm fighting with another error, which is _"conversion to dalvik format failed with error -1"_

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem with the help of the hint I found here: http://viktorbresan.blogspot.com.tr/2012/10/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with.html#comment-form . Now there is no Log output anymore. Thanks a lot!