# Logcat during production

Tags: java, android

I used to use my a custom class that is responsible for logging with the following implementation

```
public class Logger {

     public final static boolean DEBUG = true;

     public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
         if(DEBUG)
             Log.d(tag, msg);
     }

}
```

When I release the app I set the flag to false, however I was said that the following method is not that efficient since the `Strings` are still being allocated and then deallocated in the memory

the logger being used like that:

```
Logger.d("tag", "message");
```

or maybe like that, by doing that the `StringBuilder` will be invoked

```
Logger.d("tag", "server response: " + response + " timing: " + timing);
```

Is that true, can't the dalvik/compiler optimize it to prevent such behaviour. and if so, is there something I can do to optimize it other than moving the if outside?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Proguard to entirely remove logging from bytecode of your production apk. On debug version just disable "proguarding".

E.g.:

[Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this)

By the way, few unnecesary string concatenations are not good, but usually are not that hard (unless you are doing it many times in the loop), so don't demonize it :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just just declare two `String` variables in your `Activity` and reuse them whenever you add a log entry like so:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
{
    String tag;
    String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Rest of Activity
```

Then whenever you want to add a log entry simply set the tag/message value:

```
tag = "myTag";
message = "myMessage";
Logger.d(tag, message);
```

This way your `if` check remains inside `Logger` and no additional memory is allocated.

Comment: that might be great if you have the same log all over the code, but usually it's dynamically generated (I'll add example to the question)