# Stop Java Library from Sending Log Messages

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

I am using an open Source Library for my Android Application. However its developers did not remove all the Log statements before releasing it. This causes a lot of ruckus in LogCat.

**Is there a way to turn the Log Messages from a specific Java library Off ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662

This is a possible solution. Are you asking for this?

Answer (score 0):

**You can Filter LogCat** outputs by some specific Tag names , like (adb shell)

```
adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"
```

Comment: Not when I release my application and someone else can see the values coming through in LogCat....... Or am I missing something ?

Comment: I think that is not possible.Because there is no APIs available for such mechanism in Android Logging Framework

Comment: Is it possible to completely shut down logging in Android Application before the production apk is released ?