# Android what's the best way to hide logs?

Tags: android, logging

so.. I'm using Log.d("", ""); in many places in my app for debuging.
but I don't want those logs in the store.

right now in order to hide them in the store version, I created a Constant.class and put a boolean there called debugMode, and wrapped every log i have in an if statement like this :

```
if (Constant.debugMode) {
Log.d(TAG, "check123");
}
```

and then when I build a google store apk I change that boolean to true instead of false.

that's kind of clumsy in my opinion, is there any more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a simple logger class that has public static methods and a swich to enable logs only for debug versions of your app. Here is a sample code.

```
public class Logger {

    public static final boolean D = BuildConfig.DEBUG;

    public static void LogInfo(String TAG, String msg) {
        if (D) {
            Log.i(TAG, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void LogWarrning(String TAG, String msg) {
        if (D) {
            Log.w(TAG, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void LogDebug(String TAG, String msg) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void LogError(String TAG, String msg) {
        if (D) {
            Log.e(TAG, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Logger.LogDebug("Test", "Example");
```

This way you can keep the if clauses in one place and don't have to worry about them. Also I don't think it clumsy this way.

Answer (score 0):

> I find a far easier solution is to forget all the if checks all over
>   the place and just use ProGuard to strip out any Log.d() or Log.v()
>   method calls when we call our Ant release target.
>
> That way, we always have the debug info being output for regular
>   builds and don't have to make any code changes for release builds.
>   ProGuard can also do multiple passes over the bytecode to remove other
>   undesired statements, empty blocks and can automatically inline short
>   methods where appropriate.
>
> For example, here's a very basic ProGuard config for Android:
>
> -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontobfuscate
>   -forceprocessing
>   -optimizationpasses 5
>
> -keep class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
>       public static *** d(...);
>       public static *** v(...); } So you would save that to a file, then call ProGuard from Ant, passing in your just-compiled JAR and the
>   Android platform JAR you're using.

@REF:[Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this)