# how to turn off log cat output after making release apk when minifyenabled is true in android

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, logcat

First of all please dont take it as a duplicate question as I have tried all the solution from this forum but failed to get my answer.

From my gradle.build file I have made:

minifyenabled to true and then write this line of code in my project's proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

but this doesnt change anything in my project, when I make a release version apk and run on my device all log still shows! Is there anything new that I have to do now?

Comment: In the app I work on, we ended up removing almost all of our logging statements and wrapping the few that remain within `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { /* logging */ }` blocks. We're not using this `assumenosideeffects` thing at all.

Comment: please make a complete solution as an answer, I will mark it as accepted if it works :)

Comment: first of all some log messages are coming from one of my library classes, I cant access those classes, how can I write the code on that library? @Barend

Comment: you cannot apply this to libraries after the fact. You'd have to get the libraries updated for that to work. If they're open source it's possible…

Comment: The other thing you could do is use  ProGuard to strip out the logging. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-assumenosideeffects` is skipped when `-dontoptimize` is set ([relevant documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#optimizationoptions)), which I believe is the default for the standard ProGuard configuration file provided by Android.

If you'd like to use `-assumenosideeffects` then you will have to use the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` configuration file from the `{your-sdk-dir}/tools/proguard/` directory. This will be also applied to any libraries which you use in your application project, so their logging will be stripped as well if you're worried about that.

As an alternative you could use a wrapper class for Android's `Log`, wrapping all calls in conditions checking the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` flag, which is nicer since you will have a single access point for these checks as opposed to littering them all over your classes.

It is however worth noting that for the latter solution you will not get a performance improvement for release builds, as if you have lots of logging where you concatenate strings for your messages these will still be evaluated at runtime for the method calls (even if they will never be printed out).

Comment: I marked you answer as a verymuch valuable option, I will try today and let you know

Comment: or can you give me a simple copy paste solution that will prevent everylog from my process including my library logs and my own logs? @Martin

Answer (score 1):

In the app I work on, we ended up using a different approach. We look carefully at our logging statements, most are used only during initial development. We remove those once a feature is done.

For the logging statements that we want to keep, we use this approach:

```
import com.mycompany.mypackage.BuildConfig;
import android.util.Log;

public class SomeClass {

    public void someMethod() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i("SomeClass", "Some logging");
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` field is a `public static final boolean` that is generated by the build process. In release builds this boolean is generated as `false`, which means that you get `if (false) { /* logging */ }`. The java compiler is smart enough to see that this code will never run, and leaves it out of the Java byte code entirely. When this byte code is then dexed and put into the APK, the logging is simply not there.

We're not using the `-assumenosideeffects` marker at all.