# How do I disable all logs for Google Analytics v4 for Android

Tags: android, android-logcat, google-analytics-firebase

In my app I want to turn off all logs from Google Analytics in my release build. I'm constantly seeing logs like the following:

```
Hit delivery requested: ...specifics...
Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

I've tried setting the logger to null, I've tried setting the log level to only errors. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Here's my initialization code.

```
boolean useAnalytics = MyApp.getBuildType().shouldUseAnalytics();
GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext);
ga.setDryRun(!useAnalytics);
if (useAnalytics) {
    ga.setLogger(null);
} else {
    ga.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
}
tracker = ga.newTracker(mContext.getString(R.string.ga_app_trackerid));
tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false);
tracker.setSessionTimeout(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer about disabling logging of third party libraries using pro-guard [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662)