# Disable Firebase crash reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have decided to include the Firebase Crash API 9.0.1 into my Android app. 
At the moment everything is working fine. Now I want to give my users the opportunity to disable, that Firebase is sending the Crash reports automatically.

Firebase Analytics can be disabled with this code snippet

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Does anyone of you know a similar way to disable crash reporting?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Firebase Crash Reporting when the app is running on debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396826/how-to-disable-firebase-crash-reporting-when-the-app-is-running-on-debug)

Comment: Any luck on finding a way to disable crash reporting?

Comment: See below answer of mine for similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41712248/5745574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible now. Check this, 
[Disable Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk)

Simply add the below line to your code in the first activity or even better in the Application class.

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(false);
```

To enable,

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(true);
```

This is really helpful when we have multiple build types such as Debug, Release etc.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for short answer but currently there is no official support for this.

**EDIT: 30/10/2017**

Now it is possible to enable/disable at build time adding in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

or runtime using:

```
FirebaseCrash.enableCrash(true|false);
```

More [info here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk)

Comment: I can't believe this isn't available. I mean I'm going nuts looking at crashes caused by developers and not users. :/ Android is easy to simply remove the library... Maybe iOS has a way to not compile this?

Answer (score -2):

You can find the instructions on the page:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics

**Disable Analytics collection on Android**

***Temporarily disable collection***

If you wish to temporarily disable Analytics collection, such as to get end-user consent before collecting data, you can set the value of firebase_analytics_collection_enabled to false in your app's AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag. For example:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

To re-enable collection, such as after an end-user provides consent, call the setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled() method of the FirebaseAnalytics class. For example:

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

If you need to suspend collection again for any reason, you can call

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

and collection is suspended until you re-enable it.

***Permanently deactivate collection***

If you need to deactivate Analytics collection permanently in a version of your app, set firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated to true in your app's AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag. For example:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />
```