# How do I ensure I don't use Google Analytics

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-analytics

I want to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), however it seems now I have to use it within Firebase. The Firebase terms of service say if I use Firebase Analytics I am bound by an additional set of terms of service.

I do not want any information about my app or its usage captured or shared with Google.

My question is if I implement GCM in my mobile app will it automatically be using Firebase Analytics?

If not,  how do I avoid using Firebase Analytics, or how do I turn it off completely. The google documentation is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can disable it completely but you can try with setting [setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(boolean)) to false.
Something like this in every activity:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by putting this within the application tag in your AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />
```

Also see [Disable Analytics Collection](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics)

In addition, you can apparently now [disable crash reporting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396946/3482621)

However, that may not be everything. In order to really be sure that your app is not transmitting any information to Google, you should watch the app's network traffic using a tool such as [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com).

But it's hard to be sure that no usage or other significant data is going to google servers. I have seen calls to the following google servers happening and it's not clear what data is being transmitted:

- app-measurement.com
- safebrowsing.google.com
- android.clients.google.com
- clients2.google.com
- android.googleapis.com

Comment: And a gazillion of others like accounts.google.com, www.gstatic.com, play.googleapis.com, etc. (and another gazillion of obfuscated URLs like https://r1-----sn-n4v7sn7yy.gvt1.com) and such.

Comment: thanks. i see what you mean. it does seem pretty hard to become confident that no significant usage data is making it back to google.

Comment: It’s probably impossible (\*) to achieve. (\*) and by impossible I meant: pretty hard, like you described. Google will always be google. (A.k.a.: 80% complete APIs and Customer Analysis for the purpose of selling ads).