# Opt out from Firebase Crash Reporting on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I want to give my users the option to opt out from reporting crashes to Firebase.

To do this, I'd like to disabled / enable Firebase Crash Reporting at runtime. As far as I know there is no official solution for this yet.

For Android though, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39322734/4134167) provides a workaround. 
Now I am looking for a way to do this on iOS. Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk?authuser=1

```
Crash.sharedInstance().crashCollectionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know in which version this feature was added?