# Fabric's Crashlytics with Firebase can't be disabled for DEBUG builds

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have an app that utilises Fabric's Crashlytics via Firebase.
The following is the first thing executed in my Applications onCreate

```
CrashlyticsCore crashlyticsCore = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
    .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(crashlyticsCore).build());
```

Nonetheless, the crashes are submitted in `DEBUG == true` mode.

I use the following versions

in my build.gradle
`classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1"`

in my app/build.gradle
`implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1"`

Unfortunately the crashes still get reported. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396946/7505436

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using firebase-crash as it is deprecated now. Your proposed answer uses that. I am using crashlytics, it is just connected with the firebase console.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [Firebase Crashlytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#enable_opt_in_reporting) explains that once reporting is enabled in an app session, it cannot be disabled.

By default, Crashlytics reporting is enabled in a `ContentProvider` named *CrashlyticsInitProvider* that executes before your `Application` instance is created.  *CrashlyticsInitProvider* enables or disables reporting based on the meta-data value `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled`, which by default is true.

If you want reporting disabled, it's critical that the manifest meta-data be present and set to false:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Look in the logcat during app initialization for the message:

```
CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
```

If the message is present, `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` is true.  If the message is not present, you have successfully set the meta-data to disable crash reporting.

If the meta-data is missing or set to true, you cannot disable reporting in your code using a call to `Fabric.with(...)`.

In a comment to another answer, you indicate that you tried disabling reporting using the meta-data and were not successful.  Check for a typo and ensure the declaration is correctly placed in the `<application>` element.  In my tests, I am able to disabling reporting using the meta-data and then enable at run time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again.

Comment: It was a few issues that together led to the problem. Your answer helped me resolve them, so I am accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem myself and this solution does not seem to be enough. I have added the meta-data, I do NOT have "CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful" in the logs, I have quadruple checked that `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` is only called on non-debug builds, I have version 2.9.3 of the SDK, and I am still getting crash reports. Please help - if there is nothing else to do I'll try the gradle-based solution mentioned below.

Comment: I tried this, does not seem to work anymore, unfortunately. `CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful` doesn't show in the logs in DEBUG builds anymore, but crashes are still sent to my Console. `firebase_core_version = '16.0.5'` & `firebase_crashlytics_version = '2.9.6'`

Comment: as of the latest Crashlytics it prints out `I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.6.29`

Answer (score 133):

Correct answers have been posted by [Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49546854/982852) and [niqueco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547347/9828529) already however it seems kinda tedious to change the meta-data value every time you are building an actual release APK thus here's a solution that uses so called [manifestPlaceholder](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) and changes the value automatically to `true`or `false` depending on the `buildType`.

**Add the following to your apps `build.gradle`**

```
android {

    // ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"false"]
        }
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"true"]
        }
    }

}
```

**And this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<manifest ... >

    <application ...>

        // ...

        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="${enableCrashReporting}" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

You can verify the current value by clicking on the `Merged Manifest` tab once you have opened the AndroidManifest.xml. You should see something like this:

[image: Merged manifest meta-data value for crash reporting]

Comment: It links the other answers that explain the reasoning AND it also provides a clean SOLUTION.

Comment: Best and more generic approach. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I do it. I upvoted your answer. However, I leave the accepted answer as is, because it pointed me to the correct solution.

Comment: Thats some nice solution!

Answer (score 9):

I've finally found the issue. Crashlytics is initialized from a content provider, so by the time you try to disable from Application's `onCreate()` it's too late. Going through the decompiled code I've seen that you can disable that initialization by adding metadata to the <application> element in the manifest.

So, what I do is this... I've added this to app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="<your app package>">

   <application>
           <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
   </application>

</manifest>
```

I've also disabled Crashlytics in the app module gradle build file by adding:

```
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
```

To my surprise I didn't need to do the `Fabric.with(...)` thing. The above was enough.

It's working fine: no reports.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again.

Comment: ext.enableCrashlytics = false
 This line is crashing my app with below message - "This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,"

Comment: @AjithMemana This is working for old Fabric Crashlytics. Not Fabric's Crashlytics with Firebase that is the question is about it. For that look at the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

I think it is possible to do it from code as well if you switched to firebase crashlytics and removed fabric crashlytics :
[link to firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_1)

So in the onCreate of your application class :

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```

Comment: Unable to see the crashes for dev. How can I enable the crashes

Answer (score 3):

Got this information from android documentation
[Customize your Firebase Crash Reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0)

Enable opt-in reporting:
By default, Firebase Crashlytics automatically collects crash reports for all your app's users. To give users more control over the data they send, you can enable opt-in reporting instead.

To do that, you have to disable automatic collection and initialize Crashlytics only for opt-in users.

Turn off automatic collection with a meta-data tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Enable collection for selected users by initializing Crashlytics from one of your app's activities:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable `Crashlytics` of app’s build.gradle. [Disable Crashlytics for Debug Builds](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
          // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
          ext.enableCrashlytics = false
          ...
```

Comment: Thanks again, but I need to do it at runtime for a couple of reasons. Any idea why `.disabled` is not working? It is working perfectly in other apps, where I do not have Firebase connected. It seems to be a firebase Bug, no?

Comment: You need to do `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` in your gradle and `CrashlyticsCore crashlyticsCore = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
    .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(crashlyticsCore).build());` in your application class

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. It still deployes the crashes produced in debug mode. I also tried disabling it in the manifest with firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled

Comment: @peshkira Did you finally found a solution that worked for you?

Comment: @Shobhit Puri yes. Take a look at the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks @peshkira. I went through that. However I had to make an additional check for `if (!BuildConfig.DEGUG) {Fabric.with()}`. I initially thought from docs that just the manifest entry is enough.

Comment: This is working for old Fabric Crashlytics. Not Fabric's Crashlytics with Firebase that is the question is about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to completely disable Firebase Crash reporting AND also not have to add the

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
```

dependency, then follow [@reVerse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135955/923920)'s answer but also add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ...>

    // ...

    <meta-data 
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" 
            android:value="${enableCrashReporting}" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
            android:value="true"/>
</application>
```