# Disable firebase crashlytics for Android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am developing an android app and have integrated the firebase and firebase crashlytics SDK.

I want to allow the user to disable crash reporting (to ensure GDPR compliance - I assume crash reports are related to GDPR) so need a way for the user to be able to disable it via the apps settings.

I found the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk but when I try and the line:

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Android Studio gives me the error `cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseCrash'`

This needs to be done programatically at runtime of the app.

Comment: are you using the latest version of firebase ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disable Crashlytics at runtime

```
// Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
    .build();

    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

> Ex

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
    .build();

    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

> More

```
boolean Agrees = value;
if(Agrees)
{
    Fabric.with(this,new Crashlytics());
}
else
 {
   CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(true).build();
   Fabric.with(this,  new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());

throw new RuntimeException("why doesn't this show up in Firebase Crashlytics?");
 }
```

> **Edit 2**

Ref : [Fabric's Crashlytics with Firebase can't be disabled for DEBUG builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528780/fabrics-crashlytics-with-firebase-cant-be-disabled-for-debug-builds/49546854#49546854)

The [Firebase Crashlytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#enable_opt_in_reporting) explains that once reporting is enabled in an app session, it cannot be disabled.

By default, Crashlytics reporting is enabled in a `ContentProvider` named *CrashlyticsInitProvider* that executes before your `Application` instance is created.  *CrashlyticsInitProvider* enables or disables reporting based on the meta-data value `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled`, which by default is true.

If you want reporting disabled, it's critical that the manifest meta-data be present and set to false:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Look in the logcat during app initialization for the message:

```
CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
```

If the message is present, `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` is true.  If the message is not present, you have successfully set the meta-data to disable crash reporting.

If the meta-data is missing or set to true, you cannot disable reporting in your code using a call to `Fabric.with(...)`.

In a comment to another answer, you indicate that you tried disabling reporting using the meta-data and were not successful.  Check for a typo and ensure the declaration is correctly placed in the `<application>` element.  In my tests, I am able to disabling reporting using the meta-data and then enable at run time.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was after, you'd think Google would be able to point their searches away from outdated documentation of their products

Comment: Sorry, it is working I made a mistake. I used the meta-data name from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk) (it was "firebase_crash_collection_enabled") and didn't notice that the name in your example is different.

Comment: Your comment about ensuring it is in the <application> block was spot on.  FWIW: output now confiirmes that it was skipped with the following message in logs:

`CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization`

Answer (score 19):

**In your module build gradle...**

```
    release {
        //true value to send the crashlytics to the firebase
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "true"]
    }

    debug {
        //false value to stop sending the crashlytics to the firebase
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
    }
```

**In the manifest**

```
 <meta-data
       android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
       android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

Comment: This worked for me (version 17.2.1). However, while disabled Crashlytics will STILL store crashes on the device. Whenever you enable again (assuming same device) it will flush out everything to the server anyway. Something to keep in mind if you are testing.

Answer (score 10):

With the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK, To disable the crash reporting, you have to use this [method : setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android&hl=es-419#reason_for_change_2)

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
}
```

Comment: I guess it should probably always be by default in the app:
`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)` so that development crashes don't obfuscate the Crashes that happen on production

Comment: This is what the doc says:  
> whether to enable automatic data collection. ***When set to `false`, the new value does not apply until the next run of the app***. If you want to disable data collection by default for all app runs, add the `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` flag to your app's AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to completely disable Firebase Crash reporting AND also not have to add the

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
```

dependency, then:

Add this to your app's build.gradle:

```
android {

    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"false"]
        ....
    }

}
```

and then also add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ...>

    // ...

    <meta-data 
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" 
            android:value="${enableCrashReporting}" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
            android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

`FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(true);` is no longer supported in new version of Firebase Crash which is called Crashlytics. For More https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(true);
```

is replaced by

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Take a look 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting#set_up_manual_initialization

Answer (score 1):

With new Firebase Crashlytics beta replacing Fabric one:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Do you have a link about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable automatic data collection (Manifest)

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

2. Enable it if not debug build on your Application.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```