# Disable crashlytics/Fabric at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I want to disable the `crashlytics` at run time in iOS app. 
I could see it is possible using the latest Firebase api. How to do this with old `Fabric/Crashlytics` api?

Update: My app will get locked if the user goes to background, if the app is locked then without user authentication I shouldn't call any api(http request, accessing database). So I want to restrict the crashlytics api as well. When the app comes to foreground, `crashlytics/fabric` calling the http request so I want to avoid this if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: You have given no context as to why/when you want to do this. Without that this question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here - you can conditionally choose to initialize or skip the initialization of Fabric with an opt-in flag set by your user, but there isn't a (supported) way to totally disable Crashlytics from running when it has already been initialized. There is a way, however, to [control your submission behavior](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#control-submission-behavior) with Crashlytics, but might not suit your use case. Also, check out [these docs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#enable-opt-in-reporting) for more information on the opt-in/opt-out mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, but I referred the opt-in docs which might not be useful for my use-case where we can't advise the user to kill the app.  Is there any other way to solve this? or Can Firebase api will work for this use case?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that in Firebase either. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#enable_opt_in_reporting for Firebase docs on opt-in reporting. You might also want to refer to this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063465/disable-firebase-crashlytics-for-android/52064284