# What is the function or usefulness of the code below in Firebase?

Tags: android, xml, firebase, crashlytics

I use firebase crashlytics for tracking errors, but I have a question regarding this code and when should I use it.

I have tried this code on the Android application that I have created

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

I want to know how to effectively use the code above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528780/fabrics-crashlytics-with-firebase-cant-be-disabled-for-debug-builds

Comment: Ok, thanks, @Peter Haddad.