# What log will end user see using logcat?

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have many Log.d() in my Android app, will my end user be able to see these logs using logcat when they connect their phone to computer? Or will these logs be stripped away in a release build?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to logcat.

You can use Timber Or refer to this method

https://stackoverrun.com/ko/q/2720163

Answer (score 0):

For a release build, the user will not able to see the log using logcat,because in release build `android:debuggable` value is set to `false` in your Manifest inside the `<application>` tag. The tells the Whether or not the application can be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

The developer has to remove the android logs before releasing the App.

Check this post on how to do so.
[How to remove all debug logging calls before building the release version of an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446248/9636037)