# How to have logs that get removed when doing release build

Tags: android, kotlin, android-r8

Is there a way to make logs get removed from the compiled APK in release builds?

In other words, I don't want to see the logs in the decompiled APK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248