# Android logs printed in both debug and release mode

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging)

In Android is there a way to disable logs/stacktrace being printed when the application is code signed and is in release mode. Is there any direct way to do it?

In Iphone i heard the logs will not be printed in release mode by default.

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging