# how to remove/ignore Log message from logcat while build the project in android?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I have created project in android in which i have put many Log messages while fixing the bugs.
Now i want to remove/ignore these Log messages to reduce the size of logcat file. pl give me some solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Manifest, set `debuggable=false`

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false">
```

Comment: This does not reduce any log output, but only disallows a debugger to attach to the running program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce what will be printed to the final log file on a production device, you can use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) within the build to "eliminate" the log.x calls within the code.

As an alternative you can also always wrap calls to the logger within

```
if (!prodcutionCode)
       log.d("Some debug logging");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use proguard to strip the production apk of logging calls. See [Is there an easy way to "deactivate logging" prior to releasing your app on the market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141751/is-there-an-easy-way-to-deactivate-logging-prior-to-releasing-your-app-on-the-m) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to strip out the log lines is to let Proguard do it for you, as in the answer to this question:

[Deactivate any calls to Log before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/deactivate-any-calls-to-log-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662)

Answer (score -2):

u can create logcat filter by ur own, so ur logcat size will decrease...
hope this will helpful to u