# Disable LogCat output in release apk?

Tags: android, logcat

Short of diligently commenting out the numerous Log.v() and Log.d() statements I planted throughout an app I have written, is there a more elegant/efficient way of compiling an app to a "release mode", so that my LogCat messages *don't show up*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this thread : [How do I enable/disable log levels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging)

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest Android Studio 2.1.3 at this moment, I followed the steps below:

Add the lines below in **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    *;
}
```

Edited **build.gradle** of app module. **minifyEnabled** has to be set to true to activate proguard. **proguard-android-optimize.txt** has to be used, in order to allow optimisations in proguard-rules.pro to run.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
```

Comment: In comments to accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this) it is said that line numbers will be broken as Log calls will be removed.