# Removing Log call using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to use proguard to strip all my logs:
I have entered the following line in my proguard-project.txt:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

And my project.properties looks like this:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Inspite of this the logs continue to show in my application. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The canonical answer for this uses slightly different syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553146/disable-logcat-output-completely-in-release-android-app/5553290#5553290

Comment: I tried that too. It doesnt work for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: If the above didn't work for you, perhaps proguard isn't running? Check to make sure you're getting files generated in `proguard`. Note that when building or deploying your app from eclipse, the _only_ time  proguard is run is when you generated a signed apk.

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. The answer I linked to is a little old but should be OK AFAIK. You might consider adding `-verbose` and/or `-whyareyoukeeping class android.util.Log` to see if that tells you anything.

Comment: check that you are getting a mappings.txt file generated by pro guard, like that you will know that proguard is running.

Comment: @jbowes- I did export, Android application(created a keystore and all that) and then used adb install to put it into my phone.@Frank-Yep . mappings.txt is there

Comment: i am out of suggestions, sorry... i am sure the solution below works, so  ....

Comment: Okay. No problem. I will just comment the logs out.

Answer (score 99):

You shouldn't specify the '*' wildcard, because that includes methods like 'Object#wait()'. Better explicitly list the methods:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

This option is only relevant if optimization is not disabled, like in `proguard-android.txt`. You have to specify `proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

or with the contemporary [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

```
buildTypes {
    releaseSomeBuildType {
        ...
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'your-proguard-file.pro'
    }
}
```

#### Resources

- [official documentation on Removing logging code](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/examples#logging)

Comment: Is there a reason for excluding the isLoggable method? I haven't used this anywhere in my project. Should I?

Comment: @Roger It tells ProGuard to remove the invocation of isLoggable if its return value isn't used, which is a useful optimization. If your project doesn't have any such invocations, that's fine.

Comment: @EricLafortune Hi, I am enabling optimization to my Android project so do I need to write `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt` both, or simply I have to add `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt` in property file? Please help me .

Comment: @Pankaj "... instead", so you need the shorter version.

Comment: Thank you... one more question is here if you don't mind... I am using ORMLite in my project, but ProGuard is not renaming the model classes. Is this normal or something bad in my ProGuard property.

Comment: totally missed proguard-android-optimize.txt when i first read this

Comment: Hi Eric, please help me. I used your suggestion and in some cases log lines are not completely removed 
Case 1. If in my code I write:
`Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "maximize:: return true");`
this is removed.

Case 2. If in my code I write:
`Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "maximize:: index=" + index + ", ratio=" + ratio);`
this become:
`new StringBuilder("maximize:: index=").append(paramInt1).append(", ratio=").append(paramInt2).toString();`

Please could you tell me how to obtain the same result for both cases?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1951805: unfortunately not.

Comment: @Lisitso You can create your own logging methods with multiple arguments, which you can then remove: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009078/removing-unused-strings-during-proguard-optimisation

Comment: It should also be noted that it removes Object methods like `Object#wait()` from ALL classes, not just the one specified.

Comment: Say, if I have a class that's similar to Log, and I wish to disable calls to all of its functions (which are also static like in Log), how do I do it?

Answer (score 16):

It's pretty late and I came across the same problem. I am using Android studio 1.3 and this is what I did.

1. Add the log methods that you want to strip in your release build in `proguard-android-optimize.txt`:

   ```
   -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
       public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
       public static int d(...);
       public static int w(...);
       public static int v(...);
       public static int i(...);
   }
   ```
2. In your build.gradle (Module: app) set proguard-android-optimize.txt as default proguard file instead of proguard-android.txt:

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           debuggable false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
       }
   }
   ```

This is because in `proguard-android.txt` optimization is turned off by default with flags

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

This worked for me, hope it helps others.

Comment: FWIW, `debuggable false` is not necessary

Comment: @AlexCohn if you want someone to debug your app then not ;)

Comment: i am getting error when using proguard-android-optimize.txt - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Comment: When do you use `isLoggable` exactly? What is its purpose? I never used it

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it like this:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static int d(...);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int e(...);
public static int wtf(...);
    }
```

and expand for all the log methods you are using.

Comment: IMHO, This does not work anymore..One has to provide specific return type int instead of ***.

Comment: @RiteshGune Fixed.

Comment: i am getting error when using proguard-android-optimize.txt java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Comment: Please ask as a new question and attach config files