# How to get android build type (debug, release) as a variable in a CMakeLists.txt file for external native build in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, build, cmake

I need to reference the android build type (debug, release) into a CMakeLists.txt file I use for building an external native library. More exactly:

```
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                   mylibname

                   # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                   PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                   # Provides the path to the library you want to import.                                                            

                   $ENV{LIBRARY_HOME}/${ANDROID_BUILD_TYPE}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libMylib.a
```

I need the equivalent of ${ANDROID_ABI}, which changes the build per abi type, in place of ${ANDROID_BUILD_TYPE} which is, of course, a name of example.
That is: which is the name of that variable? And, more generally, is there a list of them all somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that you can use `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` for this, which evaluates to `Release` or `Debug`. I'm not sure if this is the same thing as the actual Android build configurations or a separate configuration for CMake, but at least for the simple case of debug/release configurations it works. On case-sensitive platforms you might have to convert the result to lowercase.

The build arguments listed at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake are probably named directly after the variables they set.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. How do I get the value of build type in my cpp file where the actual code is. I want to return a specific string from cpp file to my main app upon the build type condition.

Comment: You should be able to differentiate between a debug and a release build with the NDEBUG macro. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17936708/8921979