# Use ProGuard to exclude Log in Android

Tags: android, logging

Is it possible to exclude the implementation of Log class from the apk using ProGuard during the build generation? So when we generate an apk, we do not have the development Logs in the class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove logs.

```
  -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
        public static int v(...);
        public static int i(...);
        public static int w(...);
        public static int d(...);
        public static int e(...);
    }
```

more information: [Removing Log call using proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard)