# How to print log only when app is in development mode?

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

I need to print logs in my application only while I am developing it. So is there a way like a boolean which will decide if my app is in a certain mode , and only allows to print log then? This will save my time from deleting logs every time I prepare for a signed build.

I tried solutions like:

```
boolean isDebuggable = 0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE);
```

and:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}`
```

They don't work like I want it to.

Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by i'm developing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Log call using proguard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard) , use these proguard rules for release mode

Comment: you want to do off logs when it it in debug mode ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ means at the time I am writing the code and all. Hence I need to print the logs to check my logic , but later on I don't need the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a static variable `debug` like this:

```
if(debug){
//do something
}
```

And set `debug` to `false` when you release the apk file.

Or create your own custom log method:

```
public static void logInfo(String tag, String msg){
    if(DEBUG){
        Log.i(tag,msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Android Studio, then try to take benefit of gradle file.

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        //Defining Log debugging
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG_WITH_STACKTRACE_MODE", "false"
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG_MODE", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG_WITH_STACKTRACE_MODE", "true"
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either way you can use static single method for printing log like shown below:

```
/**
 * @param TAG
 * @param Message
 * @param LogType
 */
public static void Log(String TAG, String Message, int LogType) {
    switch (LogType) {
        // Case 1- To Show Message as Debug
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, Message);
            break;
        // Case 2- To Show Message as Error
        case 2:
            Log.e(TAG, Message);
            break;
        // Case 3- To Show Message as Information
        case 3:
            Log.i(TAG, Message);
            break;
        // Case 4- To Show Message as Verbose
        case 4:
            Log.v(TAG, Message);
            break;
        // Case 5- To Show Message as Assert
        case 5:
            Log.w(TAG, Message);
            break;
        // Case Default- To Show Message as System Print
        default:
            System.out.println(Message);
            break;
    }
}

public static void Log(String TAG, String Message) {
    AppDelegate.Log(TAG, Message, 1);
}

/* Function to show log for error message */
public static void LogD(String Message) {
    AppDelegate.Log(Tags.DATE, "" + Message, 1);
}

/* Function to show log for error message */
public static void LogDB(String Message) {
    AppDelegate.Log(Tags.DATABASE, "" + Message, 1);
}

/* Function to show log for error message */
public static void LogE(Exception e) {
    if (e != null) {
        AppDelegate.LogE(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } else {
        AppDelegate.Log(Tags.ERROR, "exception object is also null.", 2);
    }
}

/* Function to show log for error message */
public static void LogE(OutOfMemoryError e) {
    if (e != null) {
        AppDelegate.LogE(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } else {
        AppDelegate.Log(Tags.ERROR, "exception object is also null.", 2);
    }
}

/* Function to show log for error message */
public static void LogE(String message, Exception exception) {
    if (exception != null) {
        AppDelegate.LogE("from = " + message + " => "
                + exception.getMessage());
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } else {
        AppDelegate.Log(Tags.ERROR, "exception object is also null. at "
                + message, 2);
    }
}

/**
 * Funtion to log with tag RESULT, you need to just pass the message.
 *
 * @String Message = pass your message that you want to log.
 */
public static void LogR(String Message) {
    AppDelegate.Log(Tags.RESULT, "" + Message, 1);
}

/**
 * Funtion to log with tag RESULT, you need to just pass the message.
 *
 * @String Message = pass your message that you want to log.
 */
public static void LogI(String Message) {
    AppDelegate.Log(Tags.INTERNET, "" + Message, 1);
}
```

And after that you just need to write for log in app like :

```
AppDelegate.LogT("Hello for testing purpose");
```

and when you don't want to show log then go to **AppDelegate** class and just comment out the log line. That's it. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) as a third party library. You don't need to declare `TAG` everytime in your classes and set when it shows (Debug/Release) mode.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
}
```