# How disable show logs in logcat in release mode (without if (BuildConfig.DEBUG))?

Tags: android, gradle, logcat

Android Studio 2.3.3

Here my snippet:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
  Log.d(TAG, "some message");
```

As result message "**some message**" show in logcat only in debug  mode.
In release mode this message is not show.
OK. Nice.

The problem is that I need to set this check before every `Log.d()` like this: `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`

Maybe has another solution? Without check before `Log.d()`? Maybe gradle has some settings for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Log call using proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard)