# Proguard does not remove Log.d in internal classes?

Tags: java, android, proguard, dexguard

I use

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
    public static java.lang.String getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

However when I decompile, I see the one and only custom string I used in a Log.d line in decompiled jar file. How can that be possible? Doesn't Proguard remove Log.d lines completely?

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant if proguard optimization is enabled i.e. your proguard.config is this

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: my proguard.config line is exactly like that. What's the reason behind it? How can I still use optimization but also remove strings in Log.d lines?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, it's my understanding optimisation 'has' to been enabled for the log calls to be stripped.

You could try using a Log wrapper class [(like this one)](https://gist.github.com/scottyab/a82382e460f79274bb95) to wrap `android.util.Log`. I used this approach due to a note from Eric (a.k.a Mr Proguard) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023505/31751) about how Proguard inspects the code. So this ends up with a simpler call to `Log.d(tag, string)` rather than  `Log.d(tag, string + value+ String)`

Or use DexGuard IIRC is has some explicit function for log removal. --
[***update:*** sorry my bad it's not a *explicit function* DexGuard uses the same config as you noted. I guess I was thinking the fact the decompiled code is more mangled with DexGuard.]

Comment: So, according to the wrapper class you have shared, when I use `QLog.d('myclass','my string ->'+myvalue);` and configure the Proguard to remove those lines, won't 'my string ->' be visible? Isn't it the same? What's the logic? (I have DexGuard but I am not aware of that special function :| )

Comment: Hmm, I'll need to double check by reversing one of my apps if 'my string ->' is still visible. I misread you're main objective, I thought you were trying to stop the ProGuarded app from logging.

Comment: I check the LogCat while my app is running and nothing is outputted (correctly). But ProGuard (DexGuard) does not touch that string some how.. (I see it when I decompile the dex file)