# Proguard not stripping unused generated variables after stripping out Log statements

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-log

I created a wrapper class `MyLog` to do logging for my Android app, which essentially just wraps `android.util.Log`. I want logging to be completely gone in my release app. I have the following rule defined in my proguard file:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.myapp.logging.MyLog {
    public static void d(...);
}
```

I am seeing that lines that have log statements as follows:

```
MyLog.d("Logging a boolean %b and a string %s parameter", isTrue, stringName);
```

are being shrunk to:

```
Object[] objArr = new Object[]{Boolean.valueOf(z), str};
```

and lines with log statements as follows:

```
MyLog.d("function call result: " + foo() + " end");
```

are shrunk to:

```
new Object[1][0] = foo();
```

In both cases the leftovers from obfuscation are pretty useless and might as well should've been removed.

Question:

1. Why would proguard leave unused variables in example #1 above?
2. Is there a better way to tell proguard - "Assume no side effects when you remove this method declaration and any calls to it, **along with the parameters passed** to it"?

I have read other answers related to the topic and the closest answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023505). I am not looking for solutions with BuildConfig.IS_LOGGING_ENABLED type solution where every log statement should be wrapped with this check.

Comment: Are you using optimization? Android's default proguard file has a `-dontoptimize` directive in it. If you have `getDefaultProguardFile( 'proguard-android.txt' )` in your build.gradle, try using `getDefaultProguardFile( 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' )` instead.

Comment: I am using `proguardFile file('proguard.cfg')` in my `release` build type and my rule is defined in the proguard.cfg file. Would that not work?

Comment: Proguard files can include other proguard files. Thing is that, by default, the Android build system includes a proguard file that disables optimization. Try adding `-printconfiguration` to your proguard.cfg and looking through the output. If there's `-dontoptimize` in there, optimizations are disabled.

Comment: Tried the `-printconfiguration` and did not see the `-dontoptimize` setting in the output. Any other ideas?