# Proguard keeps string constants used for logging

Tags: android, proguard, aar

Following [Removing unused strings during ProGuard optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009078/removing-unused-strings-during-proguard-optimisation) I created `Logg` class that is designed to be easily removed by Proguard:

```
public class Logg {
    public static void e(Object... args) {
        Log.e(TAG, buildString(args));
    }

    public static void d(Object... args) {
        Log.d(TAG, buildString(args));
    }
}
```

Next, I added these rules to `proguard-rules.pro` used by project:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.mypackage.Logg {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
-optimizationpasses 10
```

After the project is built, I inspect the resulting `classes.jar` file with JD-GUI and see lines like these:

```
new Object[1][0] = "Some log message";
```

The `Logg.e(...` call is removed but the constant is still there. With `-optimizationpasses 5` the line was mentioning `String` instead of `Object`.

Is there a way to make sure that Proguard will remove those Strings?