# Does logging slow down a production Android app?

Tags: java, android

Before releasing my Android app to the marketplace, should I comment out all logs?

```
Log.d(tag, "example of a log")
```

If I leave them there, will the app run slower?

Comment: You should look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging/2019563#2019563

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java doesn't support C#-style conditional compilation, so the parameters will always be evaluated. That includes any string concatenation and stuff you might be doing.

Short answer: yes.

Comment: Can you give a quantitative measure of the delay if possible?

Comment: At least a couple of function calls' worth, more if you do complex operations to figure out what you're sending (flattering arrays into strings, tight loop logs, tight loops in logs, etc). It really depends, I'd have to see your code!

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
AppLog.Log(TAG, "example of a log");
```

Instead:

```
Log.d(tag, "example of a log")
```

And this is `AppLog` class:

```
public class AppLog {

public static void Log(String tag, String message) {
    if ((BuildConfig.DEBUG)) {

        Log.d(tag, message + "");
    }
}}
```

In this case `Log` not show when app in `release` mode.

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Printing a lot of logs does slow down the app. Its a good habit to disable logging for production.

Addition : Refer this for better logging with a logging switch : [How do I enable/disable log levels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging)