# Java final boolean optimization

Tags: java, optimization

Consider the following setup:

```
// debugger class
public class Debug
{
    // setting
    public final static boolean DEBUG = false;

    void print_checked( String s )
    {
        if( DEBUG )
            System.out.print( s );
    }

    void print_unchecked( String s )
    {
        System.out.print( s );
    }
}

// worker class
public class Algorithm
{
    Debug debugger;

    public void heavyWeightAlgorithmImplementation()
    {
        // method 1
        debugger.print_checked( "This method 1" );

        // method 2
        if( debugger.DEBUG )
            debugger.print_unchecked( "Or this method 2" );
    }
}
```

I have read [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122723/will-the-compiler-optimize-this-out) that `final boolean`s in Java will most likely be optimized out. However as in my setup the if-condition is inside another class and currently implemented as in `print_checked()`. Does Java also optimize away the function call (method 1) or do I have to rewrite everything as in method 2?

EDIT #1: added static again

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the method will be inlined, so you will achieve nothing by using method 2.

Comment: Have you tried out both to see if there's any measurable difference? If this code isn't extremely time-critical, just go with the version that's easier to maintain.

Comment: you might save 0.000000000001 seconds

Comment: Even a 1ns difference becomes significant if repeated a few billion times.

Comment: It will be optimized out. Java can see that the if statement really reads `if(false)` and will remove the entire code block. I will look for the location in the JLS

Comment: @ChrisK point taken however even 2 billion nano seconds is still only 2 seconds.

Comment: But 100 debugprints with a billion iterations sums up as well..

Comment: True.  It is situation dependent.  Some projects that I have worked on would not care about that change, even in their hottest for loops.  Other projects, specifically in the low latency space would cry foul.  Millage varies.

Answer (score 2):

I had compiled example like above by jdk1.7 and opened *.class files in jd-gui.

The example:

```
class Debug
{
    // setting
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    void print_checked( String s )
    {
        if( DEBUG )
            System.out.print( s );
    }
    void print_unchecked( String s )
    {
        System.out.print( s );
    }
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] argc)
    {
        Debug debugger = new Debug();
        debugger.print_checked(" This method 1");
        if (debugger.DEBUG)
            debugger.print_unchecked( "Or this method 2");
    }
}
```

jd-gui:

```
// Debug.class
import java.io.PrintStream;
class Debug
{
  public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  void print_checked(String paramString) {
  }
  void print_unchecked(String paramString) {
    System.out.print(paramString);
  }
}
// Main.class
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    Debug localDebug = new Debug();
    localDebug.print_checked(" This method 1");
  }
}
```

As you can see method "print_checked" was stayed in the Main.class code, but "print_unchecked" was deleted. I'm not sure but I think the empty method "print_checked" may be ignored by Oracle JVM as well.

Comment: Thank you for the jd-gui hint

Answer (score 0):

Java changes over time, and it becomes more sophisticated.  So take this with a pinch of salt.

During compilation by javac, if the compiler can prove that a section of code will never be accessed then it will be removed.

At runtime, the modern Oracle JVM tends to start running the byte code in interpreted mode and in that case it will make the checks until the JVM deems the code to be 'hot' enough to be optimised.  At this time Hotspot kicks in, and it is heading towards the view that fields will be assumed to be final until it can prove otherwise.  At this time it will try to predict branches, and inline code fairly aggressively.

However if my memory recalls, the final keword on non-static fields cannot be treated by the runtime as final for optimisations because there are ways to change the values of those fields at runtime.  A pet hate of the JVM internal guys.

So out of your choices I would recommend method 1 as it reduces the number of places that if block needs to be duplicated.  However, if possible I would make the DEBUG field static and that will let the if statement get removed more reliably.

Comment: Oh, okay, my bad. Mistook the differences of C++'s `const` and Java's `final`. Will add `static` now.

Comment: A nice trick to setting the static final boolean is to infer the value of the -ea flag provided to the JVM.  That way you can keep the DEBUG turned off and stripped out of the executing code until you want it turned on, and then turn it on without a recompile.  See https://github.com/kirkch/SandboxMosaic/blob/master/lang-sandbox/src/main/java/com/mosaic/lang/system/SystemX.java#L57 for an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample the first method is IMHO better. But if you need some concatenation operations on debugging the second variant is preferrable.

Here is an example:

```
if( debugger.DEBUG )
        debugger.print_unchecked( "Or this method 2" + oldValue + "//" + newValue);
```

In this case compiler can avoid unnecessary string concatenation and invoking of toString() methods.

Here is my test:

```
public class DebuggerTest {

    static final int ITER_NUM = 5000000;
    public static class Debug
    {
        // setting
        public final static boolean DEBUG = false;
        private final List<String> collector = new ArrayList<String>(ITER_NUM);
        void print_checked( String s )
        {
            if( DEBUG )
                collector.add(s);
        }

        void print_unchecked( String s )
        {
            collector.add(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Debug debug = new Debug();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITER_NUM; i++) {
            debug.print_checked("Debug message " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("First: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        debug = new Debug();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITER_NUM; i++) {
            if (Debug.DEBUG)
                debug.print_unchecked("Debug message " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Second: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
First: 339
Second: 2
```