# Display a output statement on Android

Tags: android

My goal is to know which parts of my program is running. I usually do this by giving a **"System.out.println"** statement in Java. But since I am learning to develop applications in Android could someone please tell me the equivalent statement in Android. I do know that there is one statement called the **"Toast.maketext().show();"** but this is not working on some parts of my program.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) and to see your output of Logs enable LogCat as

*Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat.* (In eclipse)

More about Logs :

[Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html)

[Android logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging)

***Edited :***

***You can make your own filter as***

Let you are using Log.i("MyActivity", "Your message");

Process to create your own filter :

Goto Log view and click on '*create filter*'
[image]

Now one window will display as 
[image]

Now put your value as

**Filter Name :** Put any name here (This will display as tab name, as you can see in my screens TEST and TEST1.

**by Log Tag  :** MyActivity

Left other as it is.

Now run your app and goto to Log cat. click on your own filter tab.

Comment: Pankaj I am thankful for the effort you put in. I was able to understand and also get what I set to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Use android.util.Log, such as:

```
Log.i("MyClass", "This is some message");
```

The output is available in the logcat view of DDMS or from the command line with "adb logcat".

Comment: Hi Hackbod, thanks for the reply. The Logcat generates a lot of statements is there any particular way through which I can identify my line

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, declare the constant first

```
  private static final String TAG = "HELLO VINOTH";
```

Then use this in ur coding so thatlogcat will show the messages with ur Nmae

```
 Log.v(TAG,"gender value on  male button click ="+gender );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use log such as
private  String TAG="your Activity name";

Log.d(TAG, " ################item.getCount() is################"+count );

In logcat you will get :-
your Activity name  ################item.getCount() is################ 4

In this way you can easily get your line.