# Can the logcat tag be too long?

Tags: android, android-studio, tags, android-logcat

Recently, I read the codes of android native app OneTimeInitializer. There are such codes make me confused.

```
public class OneTimeInitializerService extends IntentService {

    // class name is too long
    private static final String TAG = OneTimeInitializerService.class.getSimpleName()
        .substring(0, 22);
    //...
}
```

Why it says "class name is too long" and calls "substring(0, 22)"? Does the tag of logcat should not be too long?

Comment: Yes, the limit for the log tag is 23 characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The logging tag can be at most 23 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters)

Answer (score 2):

`Log` tag's length **must be < 23**

you can check documentation detail provided under [isLoggable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable)

> IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the tag.length() > 23.

Here are some links you need to follow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355632/how-do-you-usually-tag-log-entries-android)

Don't forget to check official document of [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice.

Comment: According to the docs, this only applies for API <= 23:
 "for Nougat (7.0) releases (API <= 23) and prior, there is no tag limit of concern after this API level"

Comment: @Traendy This is tragic. I now need to change all of log.x() statements that I wrote in the API 8 days.