# Show the LogCat from Eclipse in the Emulator

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a way of viewing the LogCat messages in the android Emulator, I would like to view the LogCat that is shown in Eclipse in the screen of the Emulator or in a real device. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you connect to emulator the same way you connect to real device, so you can see all the `logcat` output in Eclipse w/o any problems by default

Comment: Yes, I can see the LogCat output in Eclipse without any problems, but I would like to see the same output but in the Emulator screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Android version below JellyBean (4.1), you can do that with an app like [`aLogcat`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=de). If you want to do it programmatically, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) will help you.

Unfortunately, Google changed LogCat so that applications can only read their own logs starting from Android 4.1 on unrooted devices.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that link you provided.

Comment: Are you using ICS or below?