# What does the number in the logcat entry mean?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have read this: [Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) as well as others and googled for answers. I find close, but no cigar.

I'm parsing a log entry from the Android log. Here's an example:

```
D/WifiStateMachine(  923): processMsg: ConnectedState
```

What is the 923? My guess is PID, but I can't verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the PID.  See [the logcat output format options](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat) for details.  You can also have it show you the thread ID along with the PID.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious and wanted a bit more "proof" since the documentation doesn't specifically mention that that number is the PID. I looked up the [source of the log formatting function](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/liblog/logprint.c#L772), and it is indeed and unsurprisingly the PID.

```
switch (p_format->format) {

    ...

    case FORMAT_BRIEF:
    default:
        prefixLen = snprintf(prefixBuf, sizeof(prefixBuf),
            "%c/%-8s(%5d): ", priChar, entry->tag, entry->pid);
        strcpy(suffixBuf, "\n");
        suffixLen = 1;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being thorough.