# Read logcat programmatically for an application

Tags: android, logcat

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) already. But it seems most of the text it shows are not in my application. How can I filter the message and let it only shows the log for my application. In another word, I want to show it like the one in Android Studio (only showing the error log from my app, showing time stamp,etc):

I tried something like "logcat -d -v time", but doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can always parse the lines from logcat yourself and ignore any tag you don't want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try following code to get logs of your application only.

```
public final class MyAppLogReader {

    private static final String TAG = MyAppLogReader.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final String processId = Integer.toString(android.os.Process
            .myPid());

    public static StringBuilder getLog() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String[] command = new String[] { "logcat", "-d", "-v", "threadtime" };

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains(processId)) {
                    builder.append(line);
                    //Code here
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLog failed", ex);
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

*Edit*

Add below permission to your `AndroidManifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Comment: I edited your post by adding -d command line parameter to logcat, else the function never returns, just waits and adds more log lines as they are posted. Also under newer versions of Android (I think from Jellybean up) and without root access, only the logcat entries generated by your own app package are included.

Comment: Don't forget to add '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />' in your manifest for this to work.

Comment: READ_LOGS

added in API level 1
String READ_LOGS
Allows an application to read the low-level system log files.

Not for use by third-party applications, because Log entries can contain the user's private information.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS

Comment: is it possible to read logs of other application using package name ?