# How to send my Logcat data to my server in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, server, logcat, android-logcat

> I'm new in android...
>    i want to see my application logcat to my
>   server. so that it became easy to see the errors..
>
> please explain step by step...

**THANKS IN ADVANCE.**

Comment: crashlytics(or similar tools) would be more easy to track errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to integrate [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html) in your android application. It will track your errors/crash event.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [TestFairy](https://www.testfairy.com/) or you can check below link, It has already answers by somebody.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27957459/1404798

[Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)