# Logs in my code do not display when getting logcat programmatically

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

My android code contains Log.e. When getting logcat programmatically, those logs are not displayed. My code for logcat is

```
                String command = "logcat MyApp:V";
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String currentLine;

                while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(currentLine);
                    result.append("\n");
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "printLog: " + result.toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957300/read-logcat-programmatically-for-an-application

Comment: I can't get logs all the times.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use result.toString.. Instead use result`Log.e(TAG, "printLog: " + result);`

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: No, this is not my problem. My problem is getting all logs from logcat file, those are generated by app.

Comment: static final String TAG = YourClassName.class.getSimpleName();

Comment: Use log inside the while loop

Comment: No my problem is completely different.