# android logcat access without root from api > 16

Tags: android, android-logcat

I need to access to my android 4.4.4 logcat files, and I want to know if there is a way to access to android logcat files (api > 16) without having to root the smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html), I do not see why you would need to root your smartphone to see the logcats.

I am using an unrooted Nexus 4 on API 19 to develop (with Android Studio), and I have no troubles viewing them.

Edit : I quite misunderstood the question. However, according to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28857/how-can-i-access-android-log-files-on-my-nexus-7-without-root-access), and [that one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/problems-accessing-message-logs-on-jelly-bean-with-alogcat), it seems it is impossible for an app to access any log file beyond its own without root access since the Jelly Bean release.

One app can still view its own logs thought (if this is what you are looking for), and you may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) on how to do it.

Comment: While the question wasn't clear about it, I expect that they want to read the log using an app on the device itself, rather than using a connected development machine.  Otherwise, as you point out this is trivial and does not require unusual access.

Comment: exactly I want  to read the log using an app on the device but the problem is that the device must be rooted !!