# How to capture Modem Radio Log in Android

Tags: android, logcat, android-log

I need to capture some information from Modem Radio Log in android. I want to do this because I need some information about `baseband` in android, and I found out that to do that I must capture modem log.

I found [Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) for capturing `logcat` logs in application, but it is an adb log `adb logcat -b radio`, and I don't know how to capture ADB log in application.

Comment: Are you searching for `adb logcat -b radio`?

Comment: Yes, can I use it inside my application?

Comment: No. You have to execute it via adb or using root permissions on current Android versions.

Comment: I want to pars the Android baseband log for information about the cellular connection. How to do this in my app?

Comment: @Robert can you please help me? How to do "or using root permissions on current Android versions." Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use below command on terminal or console after adb device connection.

adb logcat -b radio

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    //here you can add your params
    String[] commands = {"logcat"};
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String s;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        //here is your logcat
        Log.i("logcat", s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("logcat", s);
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Keep in mind that you might need root to read logcat.

UPD: Working example - https://github.com/sssemil/SampleLogcatApp

Comment: Thank you @sssmeil, it is good, but when I try this command `adb logcat -b radio` instead of yours, it doesn't work. I think it is because that ADB commands can't get executed like this. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to add "adb" if you are "inside". Just type "logcat -b radio". Not sure if same command is valid for internal logcat but you can still try. And you need root access in order to read other apps' logcat.

Comment: This command is not working without adb. When I try the original command, I receive this "cannot bind 'tcp:5038'"

Comment: Try installing Android Terminal Emulator and running `logcat` (with and without params) command in it to check if it's working.