# Display Log.e() as a Toast

Tags: java, android, debugging, toast, jsch

I'm currently working with my first app and i use try and catch code, so i give a `Log.e()` to display error messages. So i ask how to display `Log.e()` error as a `Toast`?

Here i attached my code that use JSCH

```
package beny.com.solehap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String status;

    private Boolean IsRunning;
    private String eror;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button keluar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexit);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new sshkonek().execute();
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                startActivity(login);
            }
        });

        keluar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                close();
            }
        });
    }

    public void close(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Sure to exit?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
    }


    public void konek() {
        sshkonek task = new sshkonek();
    }

    public class sshkonek extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[1000]);
        ProgressDialog loading;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            loading.setMessage("Memproses.. Mohon Tunggu");
            loading.setCancelable(true);
            loading.setMax(100);
            loading.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String host = "192.168.197.101";
            String user = "pi";
            String pwd = "raspberry";
            int port = 22;
            JSch js = new JSch();

            try{
                Session sesi = js.getSession(user, host, port);
                sesi.setPassword(pwd);
                sesi.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                sesi.connect(100);

                ChannelExec kanal = (ChannelExec)sesi.openChannel("exec");
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kanal.getInputStream()));
                    kanal.setOutputStream(baos);
                    kanal.setInputStream(bais);
                    //koman
                    kanal.setCommand("ls");
                    kanal.connect();
                publishProgress();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3500);
                }catch (Exception ignored){};
                 kanal.disconnect();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());

                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
            }
            return baos.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            if (unused != null && unused.equals("ERROR_IN_CODE")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error"+ Log.e(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sukses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                loading.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read logcat programmatically within application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beny Putra Petir you can do it by this code

```
catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
eror=e.toString();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
        }
```

and in toast

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error "+ eror, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Wonderfull but Toast doesn't showing up outside doinbackground

Comment: You can print a Toast in onPostExecute method.??

Comment: Thanks i solved my problem and usee your code thanks