# Access system logs on Android 7 and later

Tags: android, logging

We have a use case where we want to remotely collect system logs of Android 7 devices (and probably Android 8 in future). These are not consumer devices and we are using them for our business purpose only.

On searching this problem all links are pointing to using `adb logcat` over USB. However, it is not possible for us since we don't have physical access to our devices. I tried running `logcat` as a process and I was able to fetch system logs. However, this kind of sounds like a hack. Is there any API or any official way to gather system logs programatically from Android App.

Example of running `logcat` process is here: [Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)

Thanks

Comment: "I tried running logcat as a process and I was able to fetch system logs" -- that only works on Android 4.0.3 and older, from `adb shell`, or on rooted devices or similar unusual scenarios. "Is there any API or any official way to gather system logs programatically from Android App." -- no, for privacy and security reasons. Apps have a tendency to log all sorts of unfortunate things, which is why in-app log access was restricted starting with Android 4.1.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just wanted to confirm when you say Android 4.0.3 and older you mean later right? Because I tried this on my Android 7 device and Android 8 emulator (both are not rooted). Running `logcat` process method works on both.

Comment: No, I mean older. [Ordinary apps cannot hold the `READ_LOGS` permission as of Android 4.1](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html). While the command will run without that permission, it should only return log messages from your own app, and a handful of system messages. Most system messages, and messages from other apps, should not be in the output. If it is, that's a significant security flaw in your particular devices.

Comment: Got it. I didn't notice that I am getting logs from only my app. Thanks for your help. :)