# How to print values coming in logcat to UI of android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, proximitysensor

I have created a proximity service which performs basic on/off of screen depending on the sensor value. I needed to time these sensor changes  so i used the following code

```
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
    val distance = event.values[0]
    val max = event.sensor.maximumRange
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    if (distance < Math.min(max, 8.toFloat())) {
        listener.onNear()
    } else {
        listener.onFar()
    }

    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    System.out.println("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds")
}
```

I am getting the values in log cat but i need to print these on my app, my app activity is in another java class called settings activity. I have added a textview called "Time taken" how to push those values of (endTime-startTime) to this textview??? or should i have to use any other layout comonent??
[My settings layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAU9U.jpg)

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set id of that `TextView` and then bindview in java and after it you can set text into `TextView`

Your XML should have this widget

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

now in your java, bind this textview with id like

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

now you have `tv` object of `TextView` that will help you to `setText()` like

```
tv.setText("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

Comment: Getting these following errors
1) function invocation 'TextView(...)' expected
2)unresolved reference tv

Comment: you need to bind with its id

Answer (score 0):

make the variables you want to access public static
and then access them by

```
    tv.setText(YourActivity.YourVariable);
```