# How to clear logcat before writing to a file programmatically in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

### Explanation

I am writing the logs to a file every 15 mins using logcat. It writes to a file properly but at 30thmin(i.e if I start writing to a file at 11:30 next it will write at 11:45 and at 12:00) it will also add the duplicates to the file. 
Now how to clear the duplicates from the logcat so it won't write to a file?

In this method, I set the time so that it will write to a file every 15mins.

`SetAlarm method`

```
private void ScheduleLogSaverService()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent logSaverIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(LogSaverService));
            logSaverIntent.PutExtra("LogPath", Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "LogFile");

            if (!Utils.IsServiceAlarmSet(logSaverIntent, 2561, this))
            {
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 2561, logSaverIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                Utils.SetAlarm(pendingIntent, AlarmManager.IntervalFifteenMinutes, this);

                Log.Debug("MonoVeP", "MainActivity::ScheduleLogSaverService - alarm set");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug("MonoVeP", "MainActivity::ScheduleLogSaverService - alarm already set");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("MonoVeP", "MainActivity::ScheduleLogSaverService threw an exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Clearing the logcat and then  writing the logs to a file

`write method`

```
private void WriteLog()
    {
        Java.Lang.Process process = null;
        string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "LogFile"
        File _logfile = new File(path+"log.txt");
        try
        {
            process = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("logcat -c");

            string[] command = { "logcat", "-d", "-v", "threadtime" };

            process = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(command);

            using (BufferedReader insr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.InputStream)))
            using (BufferedWriter logFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(_logFile, true))) //true = append
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = insr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!line.Contains("MonoAndroid")) continue;

                    //builder.Append(line);
                    logFile.Write(line + "\r\n"); //If your goal is to see it in Notepad, change the line separator to \r\n
                    logFile.NewLine();
                    logFile.Flush();
                }
            }

           // DeleteLogsFromCache();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.Debug("MonoVeP", "LogSaverService :: WriteLog() failed: " + ex);
            process?.Destroy();
        }
    }
```

I even tried this code to clear the logcat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955495/8329826 and https://coderwall.com/p/s0wo3q/android-read-the-logcat-programmatically still it won't stop from writing duplicate to a file.

### Question

How to clear the logcat so that it won't write the duplicates to the file? Please suggest.

### Answer

In `LogSaverService` class

The problem was with  `string path` variable i declared it globally and also inside the `WriteLog()` method. When i removed the global declaration duplication got stopped, other than that there was no problem in the code.

Comment: Could a solution be, to keep track of last line logged, and simply start from that instead - then no need for clearing log?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder();
    process.command("logcat", "-c");
    process.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        process.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your post but i have tried this but didn't work for me.@Mathias Kirkegaard

Comment: ok - I have created a test project (with some other stuff in it), but I have created an activity called log-cat, which seems to clear the log cat (not in the IDE, but when I read from it, it is cleared) - you can have a look, and see if it helps :)  https://github.com/mathiasnielsen/mathirialdesign

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try as per you did and let you know @ Mathias Kirkegaard

Comment: @ Mathias Kirkegaard-It's not that every time it writes the duplicates to a file only at every 30mins it writes the duplicate, don't understand why it's happening.