# ViewModel in Kotlin: Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I am trying to implement ViewModel in a 100% Kotlin app. Every piece of documentation I can find says I want to use this to get the ViewModel instance:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)
```

According to the docs, I should be able to import this with:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
```

This import is unresolved though. I am using the following in my build file:

```
def androidArchVersion = '1.1.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$androidArchVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$androidArchVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycler:compiler:$androidArchVersion"
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$androidArchVersion"
```

Why can't I access `ViewModelProviders`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Include the following as a dependency:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

The equivalent AndroidX dependency is:

```
"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:VERSION"
```

in where VERSION can be replaced for Current Stable, Beta or Alpha values given [in this official link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

This dependency is for both ViewModel and LiveData and thus would not require you to give separate dependencies for the same either; i.e. the first two dependencies indicated by you can be replaced by the aforementioned lifecycle extensions dependency.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue!

Comment: After adding this line, I still had the same problem. Finally, I found that I was using ViewModelProvider without the "s" at the end. 30 min trying to figure it out this. Thanks!

Comment: The equivalent AndroidX dependency is `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"`.

Comment: What about `activityViewModels`?

Comment: For the love of all things Holy. ... `s` for the win.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was missing :

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me, just you answered 5 hours ago

Comment: I did all the suggestions and nothing worked but to include this dependency

Answer (score 6):

**ViewModelProviders** is deprecated in 1.1.0

Check this android docs
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

I am using 2.3.1 and add below dependency in **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
```

Declare ViewModel in your **Kotlin** code as per below:

```
private val cartViewModel: CartViewModel by viewModels()
```

Still, if you facing below error like

> `Unresolved reference: viewModels`

Then need to add below below dependency in **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
```

`OR`

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Comment: All the other answer spam did not work. The real solution was to provide `// Main
  val main_version = "1.4.0"
  implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$main_version")
  implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$main_version")`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what [Sup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934785/4547911) suggested, you'll have to correct `lifecycler:compiler` to `lifecycle:compiler` - the Gradle sync shouldn't even complete successfully with this typo.

Secondly, the standard android annotation processing ("annotationProcessor") doesn't really work with Kotlin. Instead, use Kotlin's kapt.

At the top of your build.gradle file, add the following:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`.

And in your dependencies section, replace occurences of `annotationProcessor` (like the above one) with `kapt`, e.g.

`kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"`

Comment: I figured this suggestion would show. I did test this, but kept that separate since it didn't fix the unresolved reference issue. Thanks for the not, and the typo catch (which did sync for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

I solve this by doing like this.
implement this dependency

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

then call my ViewModel class

```
homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved with this dependency for me

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this kind of problem in AndroidStudio 3.0.1 and solved by adding 
following dependencies in the proper build.gradle:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

version code may be different as AndroidStudio tells you if it differs.

Answer (score 1):

If the above "adding/updating dependecies" did not resolve your issue then try to **restart** your android studio. It´s just to root, I do not see any major issue with it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If someone want androidx, then, first - in build.gradle (app):

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

Second - in file with code:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
```

And third - use it:

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)
```

Or use it like this (if needed ViewModelFactory):

```
ViewModelProvider(this, CustomViewModelFactory).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why there are soo many solutions to this problem however while none of these worked for me, I did find a solution in my case.

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"
```

Comment: The original question and answer are old enough that the dependency coordinates and contents have changed since they were posted, and folks have contributed answers over time that are relevant to different causes of the same general issue. I'm glad you found a solution to the issue as it stands for you now, and I might recommend posting your own question and answer for this problem to better reflect the current way the dependencies are set up!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be resolved by targeting minSdkVersion to 21.

If you have `minSdkVersion 21` or higher, you won't need `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    } 
}
```

project e app level