# Android: How do I show my own app's logs inside itself?

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, logcat

I am more of a Unix guy, and I am not very familiar with Android development; I am trying to modify some opensource app to better suit my needs. I need to be able to view the logs of this app on my Android device (without using a computer and `adb`).

How do I save the log as a text file, or open it in the default text editor of the device, or otherwise make it suitably "viewable" by the user? I know getting the whole system log needs root, but just getting my own logs should be possible?

I appreciate it if you give the solution in Kotlin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application