# Hide the debug logs from Ormlite

Tags: android, logging, log4j, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite library for a android studio project. Many messages are comming from Ormlite on debug mode. It make me can't see other messages. Please help me hide the logs from Ormlite.

Example for a line:

```
07-28 14:54:55.508  14581-21079/com.paktor I/System.out﹕ 2014-07-28 14:54:55,513 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement prepared statement
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm disabling logging programmatically by using line like:

```
System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "ERROR");
```

It's working for me because to identify if message should be logged ORMLite firstly trying to get Logger type from by using method:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class<?> clazz)
```

For Android it should return basic Android logger (android.util.Log). But for me it is always returning ORMLite Local logger (com.j256.ormlite.logger.LocalLog). And this logger level is setting up by property LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY.

If it is not working then it means that ORMLite somehow using Android logging and you just should set level of Android Logger

Answer (score 0):

The [ORMLite documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html) is actually pretty good.  If you looked for [Android logging](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging) in the manual, you would have learned about how to set the logging from the adb shell.  You can set the level for all ORMLite messages to `WARN` to stop the verbosity.

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.ORMLite WARN
```

You can also do this programmatically.  See the following answer:

> [How do I enable/disable log levels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging/2019563#2019563)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but seems there solutions don't work for my device. I tried there ways:
in code, I added:
System.setProperty("log.tag.ORMLite", "WARN"); and System.setProperty("log.tag.ORMLite", String.value(Log.WARN));
and try run "adb shell setprop log.tag.ORMLite WARN". all of them haven't worked. I still see debug messages from Ormlite