# Does one have to enclose an android logging statement in an if(DEBUG)?

Tags: android

I was surprised to learn that one has to enclose an android logging statement in an

```
if(DEBUG) {
  Slog.d(...);
}
```

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020964/398348)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020964/398348

It is cumbersome.

In the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html), it seems to say that one does not have to - the 
api seems similar to log4j where the log level is configured via external means using a properties file, and only logs above the log level are output.

I would have expected that the implementation of `Log.d()` would have the `if()` inside it, so that the developer does not have to enclose it.

```
class Log {
  void d() {
    if(DEBUG) {....}
  }
...
}
```

Can someone please clarify?

Note: I do not wish to use proguard as mentioned in several places.

Answer (score 0):

I use it all the time. Really helps when you publish your application.
You really don't want all that logging printing at a production app.
By using a simple static boolean `DEBUG` you can easily turn debugging on and off.

Comment: how do you set the value of DEBUG - inside your code? do you have to recompile

Comment: Use it as a `public static boolean` variable in your code.
For example I'd use a `Helper` class which holds my global flags and a statement checking for that would be like `if ( Helper.DEBUG){// code}`

Comment: So you have to recompile